# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified ON SELECT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, invalidoperationexception, entity-framework-6.1

We are encountering this error on a particular query in our application about 1 in 3 times:

```
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.VerifyEntityValueIsEditable(StateManagerTypeMetadata typeMetadata, Int32 ordinal, String memberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.GetAndValidateChangeMemberInfo(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName, StateManagerTypeMetadata& typeMetadata, String& changingMemberName, Object& changingObject)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntry.System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityChangeTracker.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.UpdateForeignKeyValues(IEntityWrapper dependentEntity, IEntityWrapper principalEntity, Dictionary`2 changedFKs, Boolean forceChange)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.UpdateDependentEndForeignKey(RelatedEnd targetRelatedEnd, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey(EntityKey value, Boolean forceFixup)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean replaceExistingRef)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean replaceAddedRefs, EntitySetBase restrictTo)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(EntityEntry newEntry, Boolean replaceAddedRefs)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntity[TEntity](IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
....project specific stack elements
```

The query in question is simple a select query:

```
var set = ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TModel>();
set = set.WithMergeOption(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges)
var results = set.Where(p => (!p.IsArchived && !p.IsDeleted))
    .Include(w => w.CurrentPlaceStructure)
    .Include(o => o.Room.Wing.Location)
    .Include(r => r.Residencies)
    .Include(r => r.PlaceStructures)
    .Include(r => r.Room.RoomStructures)
    .ToList();
```

The error message & google suggest that this error occurs when attempting to modify the Id value. However this is just a select statement, we aren't modifying anything in this query. Note that other queries have run on the DbContext prior to this so other objects may already be in the context.

Why would this occur on a select statement?

Why would it only occur about every 1 in 3 times?

What compounding factors might contribute to this error message?

Comment: The error may not be occurring where it is reporting the error.  Funny things happen when you don't have exception handlers (try/catch) in every method.  When an exception occur the compiled code moves up the execution stack until the 1st exception handler is found.  Linq have built in exception handler.  So the error is occurring before this code is ever executed.  Find the code that is really changing the id.

Comment: Thanks, the stack trace I see in the exception matches the breakpoint raised so I believe it is occurring in the location indicated. It appears to be happening inside Entity Framework while it is executing the ToList() query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

It turns out the same DbContext was being utilized simultaneously in multiple threads. EF6 is not thread safe for this usage therefore random internal errors were occurring.